# Jquery .append() deleting spacing of text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have question.questionText data like this(There is some space and enter):

[image]

If i append question.questionText like this:

[image]

Jquery deleting spacing. Look:

[image]

What can i do for this? I want my spacing.

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery. Browsers automatically reformat text, unless you put it in a `<pre>` block or use `white-space: pre` CSS style.

Comment: Thank you, i used `white-space` css and it works. Can you answer this question? I can't close post